# multiple underscores in elasticsearch field name with python elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm attempting to understand why a field with a single underscore, `mods_genre` would behave differently from a field with 1+ underscores, e.g. `mods__genre` when using the python [elasticsearch-dsl client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py).

Using ElasticSearch version `5.5.1`, and python `3.5`.

The following is the code I'm working with to select all documents where a field matches a value.

This example is searching an index, `foo`, with field names that have only single underscores, and returns results as expected (as I've confirmed this field is populated with this value):

```
# query against index with single underscores in field name
query = Search(using=es_handle, index='foo')
query = query.filter(Q('term', **{'%s.keyword' % 'mods_genre' : 'biography'}))
query_results = query.execute()

In [16]: query_results.hits.total
Out[16]: 6
```

However, with very similar code, but querying an index that has field names with multiple underscores in a row, `bar`, I'm getting zero results:

```
# query against index with multiple underscores in field name
query = Search(using=es_handle, index='bar')
query = query.filter(Q('term', **{'%s.keyword' % 'mods__genre' : 'biography'}))
query_results = query.execute()

In [16]: query_results.hits.total
Out[16]: 0
```

Any insight into why this might be the case?  I understand that field names that begin with an underscore are reserved, but have not stumbled on any documentation that indicates underscores within the field -- *specifically multiple ones in a row* -- would be problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because `elasticsearch-dsl-py` replaces double underscores `__` in field names by a dot `.`. This can be seen on lines 222-223 in [`utils.py`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/605d7570e2a1501f319fdc74ad8d8270a5e61ea2/elasticsearch_dsl/utils.py#L222-L223). So basically, the second query is actually made on `mods.genre.keyword`, which is probably not what you expect.

More info on the context can be seen in [issue #28](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/28), but basically they wanted to take a concept similar to what is done in Django CRM.

Comment: Ah-ha! Didn't think to consider `elasticsearch-dsl-py`, makes perfect sense. Thanks!